# jQuery $.ajaxError preventing ajax promise from being rejected

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have a WebApp with a lot of ajax calls, so I did the following to clean up things:

- I defined an ajax call with default values:

  ```
  $.ajaxCall = function (Params){
      return $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",        
          data: Params.data,
          url: Params.url,
      });
  };
  ```
- I defined a global ajax errors handler:

  ```
  $(document).ajaxError(function( event, xhr, settings, error ) {

      if(xhr.hasOwnProperty("responseJSON") 
          && xhr.responseJSON.hasOwnProperty("Message")) {

          let data = settings.hasOwnProperty("data") ? JSON.parse(settings.data) : null;
          switch (xhr.responseJSON.Message) {                
            // Handle errors
          }
      }
  });
  ```

And now I would like somewhere to chain the promise returned by `$.ajaxCall` (that is the promise object of the deferred object returned by `$.ajax`):

```
$.ajaxCall({
    url: "WebServices/Workspace_Ajax.asmx/WebMethod",
    data: JSON.stringify(DataObject)
})
.then(successAjax, function() {
    console.log("Rejected, ajax call failed!");
});
```

But the reject handler of `then` is not called, while the `$.ajaxError` function is well called. I don't understand why the Promise is not rejected (for the case where ajax request works, the Promise is well resolved). What am I missing ?

Comment: Global `ajaxError` just overrides the local error callback. You might have to use [`global` option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in $.ajax call in such cases. Just set `global:false` in `$.ajax({...})` to see the effect.

Comment: Ok, with `global:false` I can specify a local error callback, thanks